# Scrape tables with different element positioning per page

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, scrapy

**Set-up**

I'm scraping housing ads with Scrapy, to subsequently analyse the data with pandas.

Per housing ad, I collect housing characteristics like 'size', 'rooms', etc. Which subsequently are yielded in a dictionary.

---

**Problem**

The housing ads I'm scraping display the housing characteristics in a table, which is perfectly scrapable.

However, the ads are not all containing the same characteristics, i.e. some ads display info on all possible characteristics, some ads don't.

Since most ads have some missing characteristics, tables differ per ad, e.g. 'size' could be in row 1 column 2, or row 2 column 1, or somewhere else.

Check the difference in table between [ad1](https://property-italy.immobiliare.it/62225510-penthouses-to-rent-Rome.html) and [ad2](https://property-italy.immobiliare.it/61886208-apartments-to-rent-Rome.html).

I'd like to be able to scrape all tables, and obtain as much info as possible per ad. Moreover, the info should be allocated to the right variable. I.e. '205m<sup>2</sup>' should be allocated to 'size' and not to 'rooms'.

---

**Approach**

My current approach is to scrape the variable name in the column titles first, and subsequently assign its accompanying value to the variable. I.e. scrape column title first, check if is variable 'size' and then scrape its value and assign value to variable 'size'.

Not working code:

```
for i in range(1,5):
        x = response.xpath('//*[@id="details"]/table/tr[{i}]/td[1]/text()').extract_first().strip()
        if 'size' in x:
            size = response.xpath('//*[@id="details"]/table/tr[{i}]/td[2]/text()').extract_first().strip()
        elif 'rooms' in x:
            rooms = response.xpath('//*[@id="details"]/table/tr[{i}]/td[2]/text()').extract_first().strip()
```

Intuitively, this code iterates through the column titles, checks for variables and subsequently assigns values to corresponding variable.

However, I only receive errors when I run this code. 
What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the HTML structure, you always have 4 cells per table row, each row being *a field name*, *a field value*, *another field name*, *another field value*:

```
<div class="details" id="details" >
  <strong class="sec_name">Property details</strong>

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:0px;">
          <tr>
                    <td class='title'>Ref.: </td>
        <td>Via Scarpellini (1019194)</td>

                        <td class='title'>Ad date: </td>
    <td>
      23/05/2017        </td>
                            </tr>

    <tr>          <td class='title'>Rooms: </td>
      <td> 5</td>
                              <td class='title'>Bathrooms:</td>
      <td> 3</td>
                            </tr>
    <tr>
              <td class='title'>Floor area: </td>
      <td> 292m&sup2;</td>
                                        <td class='title'>Heating: </td>
        <td> Communal</td>
                            </tr>
    ...
```

One common pattern is to loop on each table row, and work on the cells in pairs, using `following-sibling` axis in XPath.

Let's first look at each table row, using one of your links in scrapy shell (using CSS selector `div#details table tr`):

```
$ https://property-italy.immobiliare.it/62225510-penthouses-to-rent-Rome.html
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(response.css('div#details table tr'))
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\n\t      \t        \t          \t       '>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\n\t        \t        <td class="title"'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\t      <td class="title">Rooms: </td'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\n\t      \t      <td class="title">Flo'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\t      <td class="title">Terrace: </'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\t      <td class="title">Total floor'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\t      <td class="title">Garden: </t'>,
 <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'details']/descendant-or-self::*/table/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\t      <td class="title">Furniture: '>]
```

For each row we can check that it contains 4 `<td>` cells (except the first one, which is empty):

```
>>> for row in response.css('div#details table tr'):
...     pprint(row.xpath('.//td'))
... 
[]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Ref.: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>Trieste</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Ad date: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>\n\t\t  13/06/2017\t\t</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Rooms: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> 4</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Bathrooms:</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> 3</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Floor area: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> 132m²</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Heating: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> Autonomous</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Terrace: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> Yes</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Floor: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>2</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Total floors: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>3</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Garage:</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td> no</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Garden: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>Nothing</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Condition: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>excellent/refurbished</td>'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Furniture: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>Partly Furnished</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td class="title">Property type: </td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='.//td' data='<td>whole estate</td>'>]
```

In the `data=` preview of the selectors, you can see that every other `<td>` has the class `"title"`, so let's try and get that info using CSS selectors again (`td.title`):

```
>>> for row in response.css('div#details table tr'):
...     print(row.css('td.title').get())
... 
None
<td class="title">Ref.: </td>
<td class="title">Rooms: </td>
<td class="title">Floor area: </td>
<td class="title">Terrace: </td>
<td class="title">Total floors: </td>
<td class="title">Garden: </td>
<td class="title">Furniture: </td>
```

The field value is in the `<td>` that comes right after each `<td class="title">`. XPath's `following-sibling::td[1]` can be used here. It means roughly *"get me the `<td>` that is a child of the same parent as where I am (a sibling), but only the first one after me"*.
And the nice thing about Scrapy selectors is that you can chain CSS and XPath:

```
>>> for row in response.css('div#details table tr'):
...     print('---some row---')
...     for cell in row.css('td.title'):
...         print('  ---some cell---')
...         print(cell.xpath('following-sibling::td[1]').get())
... 
---some row---
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td>Trieste</td>
  ---some cell---
<td>
          13/06/2017        </td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td> 4</td>
  ---some cell---
<td> 3</td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td> 132m²</td>
  ---some cell---
<td> Autonomous</td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td> Yes</td>
  ---some cell---
<td>2</td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td>3</td>
  ---some cell---
<td> no</td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td>Nothing</td>
  ---some cell---
<td>excellent/refurbished</td>
---some row---
  ---some cell---
<td>Partly Furnished</td>
  ---some cell---
<td>whole estate</td>
```

So we have field names and field values. Let's combine the 2 in key/value pairs:

```
>>> for row in response.css('div#details table tr'):
...     for cell in row.css('td.title'):
...         print((cell.xpath('string(.)').get(), cell.xpath('string(following-sibling::td[1])').get()))
... 
('Ref.: ', 'Trieste')
('Ad date: ', '\n\t\t  13/06/2017\t\t')
('Rooms: ', ' 4')
('Bathrooms:', ' 3')
('Floor area: ', ' 132m²')
('Heating: ', ' Autonomous')
('Terrace: ', ' Yes')
('Floor: ', '2')
('Total floors: ', '3')
('Garage:', ' no')
('Garden: ', 'Nothing')
('Condition: ', 'excellent/refurbished')
('Furniture: ', 'Partly Furnished')
('Property type: ', 'whole estate')
```

You can make that into a nice Python dict with dict comprehension:

```
>>> {cell.xpath('string(.)').get():
...      cell.xpath('string(following-sibling::td[1])').get()
...  for row in response.css('div#details table tr')
...   for cell in row.css('td.title')}
{'Ref.: ': 'Trieste', 'Ad date: ': '\n\t\t  13/06/2017\t\t', 'Rooms: ': ' 4', 'Bathrooms:': ' 3', 'Floor area: ': ' 132m²', 'Heating: ': ' Autonomous', 'Terrace: ': ' Yes', 'Floor: ': '2', 'Total floors: ': '3', 'Garage:': ' no', 'Garden: ': 'Nothing', 'Condition: ': 'excellent/refurbished', 'Furniture: ': 'Partly Furnished', 'Property type: ': 'whole estate'}

>>> pprint(_)
{'Ad date: ': '\n\t\t  13/06/2017\t\t',
 'Bathrooms:': ' 3',
 'Condition: ': 'excellent/refurbished',
 'Floor area: ': ' 132m²',
 'Floor: ': '2',
 'Furniture: ': 'Partly Furnished',
 'Garage:': ' no',
 'Garden: ': 'Nothing',
 'Heating: ': ' Autonomous',
 'Property type: ': 'whole estate',
 'Ref.: ': 'Trieste',
 'Rooms: ': ' 4',
 'Terrace: ': ' Yes',
 'Total floors: ': '3'}
```

Here I'm using XPath `string()` to get the text content of each `<td>` cell but I can also use `normalize-space()` to get rid of extra whitespace:

```
>>> {cell.xpath('normalize-space(.)').get():
...      cell.xpath('normalize-space(following-sibling::td[1])').get()
...  for row in response.css('div#details table tr')
...   for cell in row.css('td.title')}
{'Ref.:': 'Trieste', 'Ad date:': '13/06/2017', 'Rooms:': '4', 'Bathrooms:': '3', 'Floor area:': '132m²', 'Heating:': 'Autonomous', 'Terrace:': 'Yes', 'Floor:': '2', 'Total floors:': '3', 'Garage:': 'no', 'Garden:': 'Nothing', 'Condition:': 'excellent/refurbished', 'Furniture:': 'Partly Furnished', 'Property type:': 'whole estate'}
>>> pprint(_)
{'Ad date:': '13/06/2017',
 'Bathrooms:': '3',
 'Condition:': 'excellent/refurbished',
 'Floor area:': '132m²',
 'Floor:': '2',
 'Furniture:': 'Partly Furnished',
 'Garage:': 'no',
 'Garden:': 'Nothing',
 'Heating:': 'Autonomous',
 'Property type:': 'whole estate',
 'Ref.:': 'Trieste',
 'Rooms:': '4',
 'Terrace:': 'Yes',
 'Total floors:': '3'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the thorough explanation, Paul. I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing , unlike the first to answer which  thought to better assess your issue created your project what I have done in the past before as well we're all Scrappy aficionados and it's fun to be honest so any downtime yeah I could see myself doing something like that, but that would be a disservice to you and I'm here to answer your question as I understood it not True ignore how we got to the problem and just restart everything and hope you understand it.  Axelrod had to read someone else's toriel or official document to get where you're now...  Lol  hold on because it's going to get a little bumpy I apologize in advance

So im writing down my response to you as far as I answer at first glance I look at this one snippet of code okay I realize quickly it's a scrappy format for itemization so it's a scrappy project I see the snippet of code that you gave me there for this logic bomb  in my head that I literally became angry at the fact that don't know what you how to interpret what your saying, troubleshooting is 90% showing steps and logs and error trace back lol... and despite the fact iI glaredover this cardinal sin the a look at that snippet... look , I want you to just take that snippet at face value and how it plays to your dilemma.

For I in range() # i will be an interger object... word.
x = response... blah [i].extract.strip() # THE BIGGEST here, not the only,issue is that your constructing thecall path to your defined item and the same time calling it as to the fact of the next line, also, when your trying to format so as to put i inside x = ... its still an interger... ?? you get that right... so not only can IT NOT be contructed it cant be called format a string
if 'whatever' in x:  # ????

And the thing is when I first started reading your question I started to sympathize with you because I've done exact same thing you're describing, real estate company you scrape listing sites so do you have a Competitive Edge and have a quick way to look for properties, every listing is a point of contact for a sale... I get it, I love it.

listen if you don't get where I'm going with this its okay, but you should for sure  be just as pationate on your ability to use that basic functions in regards to their buld and LIMITATIONS... always knowing that theres always away... a quick pythonic 1-3 lines of logic.

the concept of object obstantiation   and conversion. strings, integers, list, dictionaries though can  be mixed and be converted on to an other in one fashion or an other.  Really is a begginer concept or at least should have been something to indicate this very thing as your of course learning not just native function of python but the moveonto other useful libraries... not saying you cant handle scrapy... but its no even issue with scrapy logic rather python...

You know what's going on but do you know why here it is,  as you say,  every instance of a page being called for the itemization... Not all our uniform with which items they have so some of them will be returned as a none value.. empty value... By default the CSV item exporter  argument is set to by default to drop non value so it's skipping it and what continues to happen here is that as the next item is being called but the position in the CSV file remains the same...  Then in turn,   items  end up under the incorrect key... it becomes a mess.  I sympathize with you,  efforts to help in my own way I suppose I challenge you to try and think oven easy solution that does not require you to try to over exert yourself make creating a wheel but end up with a fish lol

Since when an item returns as a none  value,  how about not skipping it can enter none of which you can set in your settings file  to do such a thing easiest solution I can think of but not foolproof because it also depends on CSV export of which dealing with a lot of different items end up having to ordering them the way you want to see them right?  That's when I would have helped any student of pythons put up then gone into Google just kind of work it out... You want to try using the if statement how about this

x = respnse.etcetc # Object created so NOW I can determine if it exist or not
if x is None:  # If its not...
    item['etc'] = "N/A" ... # HA! now nothing gets skipped
else:
    item['etc'] = response.... etc etc  # back to your path to cantnt if item exist it will be parsed... grats

And you can put this little logic straight into whatever partial that you're constructing your items... If the item doesn't exist then that value for the CSV column is as you please...

And. I've been there..  Not just the circumstances of this project and same as too many had to  deal with..  But when I first heard it getting into python and I had an issue...  To my defense was never with functions in Python but  extended libraries and module... I will go online razor and when I got fed up enough drop into Farms and ask it and I personally thank all those flames gave me a hard time because it made me want to not ever be confused as to what I'm doing what's the point of coding if you don't understand what you're saying it is a language after all is it not?  Again I hope the best for you wish I could help honestly if you look at all my attempts on here Stars responses and answers Irish try to set people straight not just give him an answer but I hope you understand that answer and try to instill the idea that is not so much drilled into people's heads these days is that the basics are fundamental....  Love Scrappy are you kidding me you can't tell me it's not fun right? I mean I don't think you'll be doing it if it wasn't,  unless you're getting paid for it which may be I guess but it's still fun you wouldn't have learned to build a research my point is how are you going to use a Canon if you can't hold up a pistol as obscure of a way of putting it on my feet I'm telling you you can be better and you will  be... But how'll I know how your journey with  python or major to dare I say lower level development is that you provided no sort of context tuition... No solid ones at least you mentioned nothing about Scrappy which would have been nice to know I know because I see that every day so I know how calling for my content looks like and Scrappy... You provided an incomplete part of where your code must have error...  And you didn't even provide the error daddy gave you which that is a cardinal sin I should let you know and our world is that if we're doing any sort of troubleshooting or development and nah group environment documentation is key coupon for people to understand what you're saying and I spent way too much time on this already and I'm afraid I came across as a smartass I don't know but I really do hope you accomplish what you wish for

Comment: 'I'm afraid I came across as a smartass' Don't worry, you only come across as a very frustrated person.